# How to divide a dataframe by the number of days in a month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  have a Pandas data frame that looks like this below:

```
            var1    var2
Time        
2000-01-31  100     200
2000-02-28  340     210
2000-03-31  590     220
...
2001-10-31  1290    101
2001-11-30  1188    100
2001-12-31  1000    100
```

I would like to create a new data frame that divides the first data frame by the number of days in each month. For instances,
2000-01-31, divide by 31.
2000-02-28, divide by 28.
2001-11-30, divide by 30.
2001-12-31, divide by 31.
And so on. The new data frame would look something like this

```
            var1_new   var2_new
Time        
2000-01-31  3.22     6.45
2000-02-28  12.14    7.5
2000-03-31  19.03    7.09
...     
2001-10-31  41.61    3.26
2001-11-30  39.6     3.33
2001-12-31  32.26    3.23
```

I constructed a small little code where I first used a timedelta to index the data frame. I took the sum of each day and month. I then created another data frame that records the number of days in a month. Finally, I tried to divide the first data frame but the number of days in a month to get the above results. However, all I get is a bunch of NaN which I have no idea why.

```
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"], unit='s')
df.index += datetime.strptime(initial_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d")

df_D=df.resample("D").sum()
df_M=df_D.resample("M").sum()

df_M["Months"] = df_M.index 

df2["DiM"] = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df_M["Months"]).dt.daysinmonth)
df_M = df_M.drop(['Months'],axis=1)

df_New = df_M / df2["DiM"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your index (`Time`) is already of type `pd.Timestamp`:

```py
df.apply(lambda col: col / df.index.days_in_month)
```